# Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2

Tags: python

I am new on TensorFlow. I was installing TensorFlow following all the instrutions that there are on the official web page.

There are a instruction that says "Verify the install" and you must type this:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

When I tried this, I got this message:

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
```

I read about it and I found some answers as "It's only a warning" or "You have to use this code" or "You have to compile", but I don't know what is the best answer to follow.

Comment: It just means you can potentially get better performance by utilizing extra features of your CPU.

Comment: And got be more clear to what @Appleoddity is saying, however you initially installed it, it simply was compiled to be as compatible as possible across multiple  systems. But the code is smart enough to detect your CPU has added capabilities that the currently installed version does not support. The answer? You can continue using it as-is and just ignore the warnings. Or you can go ahead and find a version of TensorFlow that can use AVX2 or even compile from source.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip):

> Starting with TensorFlow 1.6, binaries use [AVX instructions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#CPUs_with_AVX) which may not run on older CPUs.

This would seem to indicate that if you had the opposite issue (your CPU did *not* support AVX), you might have trouble.

In any case, [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47068709/3395469) indicates that if you want better performance running TensorFlow on the CPU (and to get rid of the warning), you will want to [build TensorFlow yourself with support for AVX instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41293077/3395469). Alternatively, [you can try downloading a precompiled version with support for these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50073238/3395469). Otherwise, this warning seems like it can safely be ignored (assuming you run into no other issues).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a GPU, you shouldn't care about AVX support because more expensive ops will be dispatched on a GPU device (unless explicitly set not to). In this case, you can simply ignore this warning by

Import OS: `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'`